# Cordova inAppBrowser inject JS for Subsequent Pages

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

I am using Cordova and the inAppBrowser plugin.

I am able to load a site in the browser and inject JS code.

However, I need the injected code on a subsequent page. The user must first log into a service (which I do not control) then on the page after login I need the JS code.

From what I understand the injected code will only run on the first page loaded in the browser.

Any suggestions on a solution?

I thought maybe I could create an iframe programically on the first page that would carry over in the login process but I dont think that will work as the inAppBrowser has security restrictions on iframe.